# Enable checkbox/es by another checkbox/es using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

using following skript to enable/disable checkboxes depend on other checkboxes. Any idea how to make this script more simple and general. For example if I will need to add another group of checkboxes in the future.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gS98E/)

HTML

```
 <form name="" id="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controller01" />Controller1
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled01" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled01" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled01" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controller02" />Controller2
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled02" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled02" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled02" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controller03" />Controller3
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled03" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled03 controller03_1" />Controller 3.1
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="controlled03 controlled03_1" />
</form>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    enable_cb();
    $(".controller01").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
    $(".controlled01").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $(".controlled01").prop("checked", false)
}

$(function () {
    enable_cb2();
    $(".controller02").click(enable_cb2);
});

function enable_cb2() {
    $(".controlled02").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $(".controlled02").prop("checked", false)
}

$(function () {
    enable_cb3();
    $(".controller03").click(enable_cb3);
});

function enable_cb3() {
    $(".controlled03").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $(".controlled03").prop("checked", false);
    $(".controlled03_1").prop("checked", false);
    $(".controlled03_1").prop("disabled", true)
}

$(function () {
    enable_cb4();
    $(".controller03_1").click(enable_cb4);
});

function enable_cb4() {
    $(".controlled03_1").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $(".controlled03_1").prop("checked", false)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed :)

```
    $(function () {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('div').next('aside').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            disabled: !this.checked,
            checked: false
        }).change()
    }).change()

    $('input[id*=selectCheckboxes]').click(function () {
        var fieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset')
        fieldset.find('[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            checked: this.checked,
            disabled: false
        })
        if (!this.checked) fieldset.find('aside [type="checkbox"]').prop({
            checked: false,
            disabled: true
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something more like

```
$('[class^=controller]').on('change', function() {
    var klass = this.className.replace('controller', 'controlled');
    $('.' + klass).prop('disabled', !this.checked)
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gS98E/2/)

Comment: Thanks, nice script. I added .prop('checked', false) to uncheck dependand checkboxes when controller is unchecked, but this seems to not working when have more than one level. Check Controller3 and Controller3.1

Comment: @Miro - Oh, didn't notice that. It gets a little more complicated for more levels, but something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/gS98E/3/

Comment: Seems to me that it is working like the script before, the idea of controller 3 and 3.1 is that checkbox next to 3.1 is controlled by 3.1 checkbox but it belong to controller3 group also, so when you unselect the controller3 it should also clear and uncheck 3.1 or any other subgroups if used.

Comment: Not sure if I make myself clear, what I need is when .controller03 is unchecked .controlled03_1 also need to be uncheckd, so far I have created if statement and if the .controller03 is not checked it will disable the .controlled03_1 but dont know how to make this function more general if I will need to add another subgroups in the future